# Sorting of STL map in c++ based on value

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, stdvector, stdmap

I've a follwing map:

```
map<int, int> mp;
mp[11] = 5;
mp[3] = 7;
mp[1] = 3;
```

If I iterate over map like:

```
for(auto it: mp) {
    cout<<it.first<<" "<<it.second<<'\n';
}
```

Then the output will be:

```
1 3
3 7
11 5
```

But I want which key has the greater value that key will appear first.
Example output for the case:

```
3 7
11 5
1 3
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Yes. @UlrichEckhardt   you are right.

Comment: Check the topic of your question as well. Doing so, remove the "in cpp", which is not very precise but probably much better expressed by the "c++" tag at your question.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt has been edited

Comment: You're still asking about "operator overloading". What brings you to the conclusion that is relevant? What I've been trying to give you a hint is that you're asking the wrong question! Also, btw, remove "in c++", that is what the tags are for and there's no need to repeat it in the topic.

Answer (score 1):

You can reverse the key and value and insert them into std::multimap, and then you can iterate through the std::multimap to get the value in the order you want.

```
    map<int, int> mp;
    mp[11] = 5;
    mp[3] = 7;
    mp[1] = 3;
    std::multimap<int, int> mulp;
    std::transform(mp.begin(), mp.end(), std::inserter(mulp, mulp.begin()),
        [](const std::pair<int, int> &p){
            return std::make_pair(p.second, p.first);
        });
    for(auto it = mulp.rbegin(); it != mulp.rend(); ++it) {
        cout<<it->second<<" "<<it->first<<'\n';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can’t, by definition. A map is a data structure that sorts its element by key.**

Answer (score 0):

You have chosen the wrong container for your requirements since `std::map` does the sorting only by the keys.

Therefore, you can switch to using the `std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>` like:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> v;
    v.emplace_back(11, 5);
    v.emplace_back(3, 7);
    v.emplace_back(1, 3);

    std::sort(
        std::begin(v), std::end(v),
        [](auto&& lhs, auto&& rhs) {
            return lhs.second > rhs.second;
        }
    );

    for (auto const& i : v) {
        std::cout << i.first << " " << i.second << std::endl;
    }
}
```

and the output would be:

```
3 7
11 5
1 3
```